# Constructor, destructor, overloaded =operator function, copy constructor do not get inherited. What this exactly means?

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
struct A
{
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"dctorA\n";
    }
};
struct B: public A
{
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout<<"dctorB\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b1;
    b1.~A();
}
```

**Output**

```
dctorA
dctorB
dctorA
```

if destructor is not inheriting then how I am able to call it through object of B ?

and I know Rule of three and five but compiler work in spit of rule followed or not. so to avoid complexity I avoided writing copy constructor and overloaded= operator.

Comment: Where did you get the information from, that those aren't inherited?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I am reading book "let us C++" and  writer is Indian.

Comment: Well it's not entirely correct, and in fact mostly wrong. [Here's a list of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), I recommend you invest in one of them instead.

Comment: By the way, you should almost never all a destructor explicitly like you do with `b1.~A()`. Especially not a destructor of a parent class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and destructor un-initialize that memory of particular object and when lifetime of that particular object going to end then it calls destructor again but that object already destroyed so it leads undefined behavior so that's why we never call destructor right ?

Comment: C++ Primer Plus is not to be confused with C++ Primer. The authors are different, and the former is viewed less favorably to the point that the Good Book List points this out.

Comment: @AbhishekMane -- Remove the `b1.~A();`, as that is totally wrong and unnecessary.  Now what is the issue you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that statement is trying to say, is that `class B` does not automatically get a constructor `B::B(int)` when you add `A::A(int)`. Similarly, `B::operator=(int)` is not automatically generated when you have `A::operator=(int)`.

The copy constructor `B::B(B const&)` can be automatically generated, in which case it expects `A::A(A const&)`. But you see from the argument that it's generated, not inherited as `B::B(A const&)`.

The destructor works the same - generated, not inherited - but that's less visible because there's no parameter.

Comment: first of all thanks  for answering. I written  constructor, copy constructor, overloaded = operator and destructor for base class and for derived class I didn't created anything. But all functionality working fine like constructor, copy constructor, overloaded = operator and destructor means compiler is generating them automatically right. This is contradicting to your first statement that constructor, overloaded = operator are not generated automatically for derived class if we write them manually in base class.

Comment: please do reply.

Comment: @AbhishekMane: I rechecked my original answer; it's correct. `operator=` like all functions can be overloaded, that's why I specifically gave `operator=(int)` as an example that is not automatically generated. Same for the converting constructor.

Comment: Thanks I got it. one last `B::operator=(B)` is automatically generated  
right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: Well, not exactly - that would take a `B` by value. That would be inconvenient; taking an argument by value requires a copy constructor. So the generated self-assignment takes a `B const&` and/or a `B&&`.

Comment: I  get it. but both `B const&` overloaded=operator and `B&&` Move overloaded=operator are automatically generated right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: For details, check your book, but both are generated only if the bases classes and members would allow it. A non-moveable member will prevent move-assignment of the containing class.

Comment: __1__ we can call constructor of base class explicitly through any member function of derived class like `base::base()` and what happen exactly is temporary object created and destroyed as that statement ends. But we can't call in such way from main function, similarly overloaded=operator __2.__  but we can't call copy constructor explicitly through member function of derived class we can just call indirectly by copying one base object to another in member function like `base b2=b1` if I try to do something like `base::base(b1)` it gives error .

Comment: __3.__  Also destructor we can't call using membership label in member functions we have to use object. so what I believe in above 3 is right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: If you've got a new question, don't put it in the comment section of an answer. Almost nobody sees it there.